# <Location> and partially non-existing directory?

Tags: apache2

In both Apache 2.2 and 2.4, I get strange behavior with `<Location /foo>` directive and requested URL http://example.com/foo/non-existing not matching.

Say my configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/apache.test"
   ServerName apache.test

   <Directory "/var/www/apache.test">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all

       # Catch non-existing resources with index.php:
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
       RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
       RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
   </Directory>

   <Location "/">
       Header set X-All "true"
   </Location>

   <Location "/foo">
       Header set X-Foo "true"
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

and *DocumentRoot* directory `/var/www/apache.test` has following content:

```
/var/www/apache.test
├── bar
│   └── baz
├── foo
│   └── qux
└── index.php
```

Note that `/foo` directory physically exists in *DocumentRoot* and directory `/foo/non-existing` does not.

Testing various URLs using: `curl -D - http://apache.test/ -o /dev/null -s | grep -F "X-"`

I get the following results:

```
URL                    | X-All? | X-Foo?
-----------------------|--------|-------
/                      |      X |
/bar/                  |      X |
/bar/baz/              |      X |
/bar/non-existing/     |      X |
/non-existing/         |      X |
/foo/                  |      X |      X
/foo/qux/              |      X |      X
/foo/non-existing/     |      X |
/foo/qux/non-existing/ |      X |
```

I thought `<Location "/foo">` would add an header for any request to http://apache.test/foo/*.

I get `<Directory>` is for file system items and `<Location>` is for dynamic URLs. So I also tried using both `<Directory>` and `<Location>` to cover all cases:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/apache.test"
   ServerName apache.test

   <Directory "/var/www/apache.test">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all

       # Catch non-existing resources with index.php:
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
       RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
       RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

       Header set X-AllDir "true"
   </Directory>
   <Location "/">
       Header set X-AllLoc "true"
   </Location>

   <Directory "/var/www/apache.test/foo">
       Header set X-FooDir "true"
   </Location>
   <Location "/foo">
       Header set X-FooLoc "true"
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I get the following results:

```
URL                    | X-AllDir? | X-AllLoc? | X-FooDir? | X-FooLoc?
-----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|----------
/                      |         X |         X |           |
/bar/                  |         X |         X |           |
/bar/baz/              |         X |         X |           |
/bar/non-existing/     |         X |         X |           |
/non-existing/         |         X |         X |           |
/foo/                  |         X |         X |         X |         X
/foo/qux/              |         X |         X |         X |         X
/foo/non-existing/     |         X |         X |           |
/foo/qux/non-existing/ |         X |         X |           |
```

I also tried only having a `<Location>` dedicated to "/foo/non-existing/":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/apache.test"
   ServerName apache.test

   <Directory "/var/www/apache.test">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all

       # Catch non-existing resources with index.php:
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
       RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
       RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
   </Directory>

   <Location "/foo/non-existing">
       Header set X-FooNonExisting "true"
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But http://apache.test/foo/non-existing still won't return the `X-FooNonExisting` header.

The way I see it, Apache somehow fails to match requests to `/foo/non-existing/` because asked asset is both for a existing directory ("/foo") and a virtual-subdir ("non-existing").

My ultimate goal is to set a given header in all the HTTP responses (for this `VirtualHost`) but the ones answering requests to
http://example.com/foo/qux/non-existing/*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this because your second to last rewrite does not match but your last rewrite does,  resulting in your requests no longer being for /foo/ by the time the mod_headers filter runs?

Comment: Can I make mod_header run before Apache loosing track of the actual URL being requested?

Comment: you can slap "early" at end of the Header directive and it runs earlier.

Another fix would be to move your rewrites out of per-directory scope, so your rewrites do not implicitly result in a new URL being procesed by the server.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "slap early". The rewrites are for the entire *DocumentRoot* and needed for all the requests (to make `index.php` handle them), where could I move them so that they are always applied and don't hamper with header? Is there a directive equivalent to `<Location>` that strictly rely on the requested URL no matter how it is rewrote?

Comment: I've found the documentation about the "early" argument of `Header` directive (I hadn't understood you were literraly giving me the steps to do ;)). Unfortunately `early` does not work in `<Directory>` nor `<Location>`.

Comment: How about pulling it out of Directory/Location and using the expression syntax as a conditional? This should get it to run before mod_rewrite in <directory>.

Comment: Tried `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/foo#">`: I get the same results, won't add the header if rewrote ("/foo/non-existing/"). Note: I noticed I now get the header when accessing "/foo/qux" (no final "/"), until now, requesting "/foo/qux" returned me 301 to "/foo/qux/" (final "/") without header. I think I'll make the PHP application handle the headers... Seems easier.